# Mongoid: add some dynamic (non-DB) fields in Model before passing it to Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Let's say I have a Model `Item` which uses `Mongoid`

```
class Item

  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title, type: String
  ...
  ...

end
```

I want to add some dynamic fields to `Item` right in Model before passing data to a Controller - because `Item` is being used by several Controllers.

For example I want to add `thumb` field which I will generate by adding `/path/to` + `filename`.

I tried some solutions with `attr_accessor`:

```
  class Item

    include Mongoid::Document

    field :title, type: String
    ...
    ...

    attr_accessor :thumb

    def prepare_data
      @thumb = "/path/to/thumb"
    end

  end
```

...And later in some Controller:

```
@items_all = Item.all
@thumbs = [] 
@items_all.each do |i]
  i.prepare_data
  @thumbs.push(i[:thumb])
end

# @thumbs >>> (empty)
```

So it seems that I'm missing some point here because it doesn't work.

Also can I avoid calling `prepare_data` each time manually? May be with help of `after_initialize`? (which didn't work for me also).

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. First I forgot to add `after_initialize :do_something` and then I found that I can user @attributes.merge!

```
  after_initialize :do_after_initialize

  def do_after_initialize
    @attributes.merge!({
                         :title => self.get_title, 
                         :type  => self.get_type,
                         :thumb => ImageUploader::thumb(self[:pictures][0]["filename"])
                         :price_f => ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency(self[:price], {:precision=>0}) 
                       })
  end
```